# MEM_SHARED, mmap, and hard links

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap, inode, hardlink

Just wondering if the key to shared memory is the file name or the inode.

I have a file called .last, which is just a hard link to a file named YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

A directory looks like this:

```
20110101143000  
.last
```

.last is just a hard link to 20110101143000.

Some time later, a new file is created

```
20110101143000  
20110622083000  
.last
```

We then delete .last, and recreate it to refer to the new file.

Our software, which is continuously running during these updates, mmaps the .last file with MAP_SHARED.  When done with a file, the software might cache it for several minutes rather than unmap it.  On a physical server, there are 12-24 instances of the software running at the same time.  Different instances often mmap the same file at about the same time.  My question is:

**Does linux use the file name to key to the shared memory, or does it use the inode?**

Given this scenario:

1. proc A mmaps .last, and does not unmap
2. a new file is written, .last is deleted, a new .last is created to link the new
   file
3. proc B mmaps the new .last, and does not unmap

If linux used the inode, then proc A and B would be seeing different blocks of memory mapped to different files, which is what we want.  If linux uses the filename, then both A and B see the same block of memory mapped to the new file.  B is fine, but A crashes when the memory in the shard block changes.

Anyone know how it actually works?  I'm going to test, but if it turns out to be name based, i am screwed unless someone knows a trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the inode, at least effectively. That is to say that once you have mapped some pages from a file they will continue to refer to that file and won't change just because the mapping of names to files changes in the filesystem.